# Setting default prop values in React Testing Library unit tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm writing some unit tests in React Testing Library and I'd like to reduce some of the repetition in each test's code. So I've created a function to render my component in each test along with the supplied props. That way I can call it in each test and just pass in any props which I'd like to change from the defaults. I've set default values for some props which are required which I hoped I could then override when needed. However Typescript throws an error if I do not explicitly pass the props for `type` and `children` when calling createComponent within the `it()`:

Error - `Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ButtonProps'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ButtonProps': children, type ts(2345)`

**Not working**

```js
export interface ButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
  type: 'button' | 'reset' | 'submit';
}


const createComponent = ({
  children = 'Button text',
  variant,
  disabled,
  type = 'button',
}: ButtonProps) =>
  render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <Button variant={variant} type={type} disabled={disabled}>
        {children}
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should render successfully', () => {
    const component = createComponent({});
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**Working**

```js
export interface ButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
  type: 'button' | 'reset' | 'submit';
}

const createComponent = ({
  children = 'Button text',
  variant,
  disabled,
  type = 'button',
}: ButtonProps) =>
  render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <Button variant={variant} type={type} disabled={disabled}>
        {children}
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should render successfully', () => {
    const component = createComponent({
      children: 'Button text',
      type: 'button',
    });
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Is there any way I can get Typescript to be aware that the props are already getting values from the default values defined in `createComponent()`?

Answer (score 1):

Typecasting should work just fine

Either `{} as ButtonProps` or `<ButtonProps>{}`

```js
describe('Button', () => {
  it('should render successfully', () => {
    const component = createComponent({} as ButtonProps);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```